# Geometry problem (Inscribed angle theorem, circumscribed circle)

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

Let A and B be two different points. Show that the points P are such that the angle APB is 90 degrees and creates a circle. Decide the the radius and mid point of the circle.

I have problems proving that the angle have to be 90 degrees, isnt it only 90 degrees if the base of the triangle in the circle is the diagonal of the circle?

Comment: Need a more precise version of what needs proof. Likely you've omitted something like "the set of points P such that" … is a circle.

Comment: This is all the information we were given, but the points A B and P creates a triangle and its easy to prove that there excists a circle that goes through all the three points.

Comment: hint: If $C$ is midpoint of $AB$, prove that $PC=AC=BC$

Comment: Maybe "show that the points P *which* are such that etc." [where the extra "which" is needed by grammar.]

Comment: Thale's Theorem should help here. As I recall it uses an equivalent to the parallel postulate. I'd avoid that if possible.

Comment: we are only allowed to use theorems from the course and Thales theorem were never mentioned sadly

Comment: We dont know that C is the midpoint, we can prove that is though and then it follows that PC= AC = BC but that dosnt prove that the angle has to be 90 degrees

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, let A be (0,0) and let B = (a,b). Then |AB| = $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

We are asking for the set of points P(x,y) such that $\angle$APB is a right angle.

Suppose P is such a point. Then |PA| = $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and |PB| = $\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$.

So $\triangle$APB is a right triangle. Then by the Pythagorean theorem:

$|PA|^2+|PB|^2 = |AB|^2$

$(x^2+y^2)+(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = (a^2+b^2)$

If we expand the left-hand side and complete the square, we get

$\left(x-\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{b}{2}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{4}\right)$.

This equation is the equation of a circle with the midpoint of |AB| as the center with radius $\frac{|AB|}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $C$ is midpoint of $AB$ and $\angle APB$ is a right angle, draw a line thru $C$ parallel to $AP$. That line will divide $PB$ in half at point $D$ (midsection theorem). It will also be perpendicular to $PB$ (because $AP$ is perpendicular to $PB$). Similarly, draw a line thru $C$ parallel to $BP$ and see that that line is perpendicular bisector to $AP$. Thus, $C$ is a center of the circumcenter.

Conversely, if you have that $CP=CA=CB$, use sum of angles to show that $\alpha+\beta=90°$

[image]